# How can i remove white blank space from bottom of scrollView in android studio

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I used two ListView inside one ScrollView like this. But my problem is that there is a white spcae bottom of the scrollview
    `

```
<ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/ss"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/sss"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:fadingEdgeLength="0dp">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true">
            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/listView1"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:divider="@null"
                android:dividerHeight="1dp"
                android:overScrollMode="never"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/listView"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:divider="@null"
                android:dividerHeight="1dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/listView1"
                android:overScrollMode="never"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

[But last time there you can see too much blank space by notice scroll bar on right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7OgmU.jpg)
[Middle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5PPc.jpg)
[From top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHgST.jpg)

Help me please. Thank you!

Comment: try changing height of both listviews to wrap_content.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this

> android:fillViewport="true"

and put inner layout height also match_parent.

Comment: Please post your full xml code.because your above piece of code is working for me...thats why i thing there is another issue .

Comment: I coverd layout with Relative layout and use Toolbar too